# How to embed SoundCloud widget in Android app

Tags: android, widget, soundcloud, oembed

How can I embed a SoundCloud widget in an Android app if I have the track's URL? Is there an official SoundCloud wrapper that integrates the widget in an app, or is a way to integrate the track's URL in Android's native player?
What's the best way of doing this?